# cannot interprete exported function and class from another project within solution?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

[image: project structure]

I have ClassB of ProjectB rely on what is defined in ProjectA.
ProjectA is built as a .lib as shown below

[image: ProjectA configuration]

ProjectB is just a exe. Below is the code.

```
#pragma once
#include "../../ProjectA/ClassA.h"
class ClassB
{
public:
    void callClassB();
};
```

```
#include "ClassB.h"

void ClassB::callClassB()
{
    //ClassA::print_msg();

    outside_classA();
}



int main()
{
    ClassB B;
    B.callClassB();
}
```

Here is the code for ProjectA.

```
#pragma once

#define EXPORT_ATTRIBUTE        __declspec(dllexport)

class EXPORT_ATTRIBUTE ClassA
{
public:
    static void print_msg();
};

void EXPORT_ATTRIBUTE outside_classA();
```

```
#include "ClassA.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void ClassA::print_msg()
{
    cout << "this is class a from project A"<<endl;
}

void outside_classA()
{
    cout << "print out side class a" << endl;
}
```

In VisualStudio:
I have the ProjectB rely on ProjectA. The **ClassA** and **outside_classA()** are exported with **__declspec(dllexport)**. And the ProjectA is built as static library **.lib** .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you read this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-static-library-cpp?view=msvc-170) carefully, it will help you. Regarding your question, you need to select the Configuration Properties > C/C++ > General property page. In the Additional Include Directories property, specify the path of the library directory.
[image]

Then the program can run using my code in `ClassB.cpp`.

```
#include "ClassB.h"
#include "../StaticLib2/ClassA.h"
#pragma comment(lib,"StaticLib2.lib")
void ClassB::callClassB()
{
    //ClassA::print_msg();

    outside_classA();
}
int main()
{
    ClassB B;
    B.callClassB();
}
```

[image]